# How to give Java input from python during runtime?

Tags: java, python, runtime, communication

Lets say I have a java program which is running something. And then I run a python program, from java, what is the fastest way to give input back to java?
I know that Jython can do what I am describing in a better way, but for the actual application I am working on I would rather not use Jython, if I can avoid it.
Note: I have a text file based system working. I'm just curious if there is a faster way?

Comment: What mechanism is used to run the python program now?

Comment: the google term you are looking for is "message passing interface"

Comment: I'm guessing `Process`

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks for the terminology tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are starting the python program something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("python", pathToProgram);
```

then you can just `print` stuff from Python. You can get it by this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Now, to get back a line of output, you can do this:

```
String line = in.readLine();
```